# Weapon Pick-Up and shoot

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity and I was wondering if anyone knows how to make the player pick up a weapon and shoot it in Unity 2D. I have already made the sprite for the gun and I've been trying to pick it up with this code:

```
public GameObject player;

void Update() {
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col) {
        if (col.tag == "Player") {
            gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(player.transform.position.x + 2, player.transform.position.y, player.transform.position.z);
        }
    }
}
```

The gun is set as a trigger and has no rigidbody. All the youtube tutorials show how to pick up an object and then destroys it, but don't show how to "hold" the object.

Answer (score 1):

If you do `player.transform.position.x + 2`, that sets the gun to the x position of the player + 2. This is not a good way of doing it.

My advice is to do it this way instead.

1. Copy the gun.
2. Parent the copy to the camera
3. Place the gun somewhere on your player.
4. Disable the gun

In your player script add this line

```
public GameObject weapon;
```

Now, in your weapon pickup script, change the player reference to whatever your player script is called instead of a GameObject.

For example, lets assume your player script is called PlayerScript.cs, instead of

```
public GameObject player;
```

You should do

```
public PlayerScript player;
```

Now, we have a reference to the player script. We can now access the weapon.
Change the OnTrigger to the following:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col) {
    if (col.tag == "Player") {
        // Set the weapon active
        player.weapon.SetActive(true);

        // Destroy this pick-up
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Also, in your code you have ontriggerenter inside the update method. That is not how it works. Make sure the method is **outside** of the update method.

Now when you touch the gun on the floor. It should now enable the gun in the players hand and destroy the one on the floor.

In the editor, drag the players gun to the `weapon` field in the player script.

Also, drag the player to the `player` field of the gun on the ground.

Hope this helps, feel free to ask more questions if this doesn't work. Keep us updated. :)

Comment: I've been sorta grounded so I couldn't try it out but I will tomorrow.